# Passing Form Serialize and list to controller is not working?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i have controller like this:

```
 public ActionResult SaveWorkOrder(DTO_WorkOrder objWork, List<DTO_PartsWO> listTry)
 {
    //something
 }
```

and model :

```
 public class DTO_WorkOrder
 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string WoNo { get; set; }
    public string ReqNo { get; set; }
    public string ReqSparepartDate { get; set; }
    public List<DTO_PartsWO> PartsList { get; set; }
 }
```

this is my javascript to pass data to controller:

```
 function SaveWorkOrder() 
 {
    debugger;
    var dd = $('#tbParts').DataTable().rows().data().toArray();
    var vDataDet = new Array();

    //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
    $.each(dd, function (i, value) {
         debugger;
         var dataDetail = {};
         dataDetail.Line = i;
         dataDetail.PartCode = value[1];
         dataDetail.PartDesc = value[2];

         vDataDet.push(dataDetail);
         debugger;
    });

    var tmp = $('#WorkOrderForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/Transactions/WorkOrder/SaveWorkOrder',
       data:  JSON.stringify({ objWork: tmp, listTry: vDataDet}),
       success: function (mdl)
       {
          debugger;
       },
       error: function (mdl)
       {
          debugger;
       }
    )}
 }
```

the codes pass the serialize form but not the list, my list null... 
please help, already code for 3 days to pass both list and serialize form but not worked

Comment: Note that, the default ``contentType`` is not a Json and ``.serialize()`` generate data like a ``queryString`` with the default contentType.

Comment: thank you for your answer Mr. @Sajid, if that's the problem so how to solve them? because I need to pass both. as you can see in my model I put list of DTO_PartWO to and I tried to fill that list by this code `data: $('#WorkOrderForm').serialize() + "&PartList="+VDataDet` but the list still null

Comment: i don't think that you can pass two complex object to your controller ,the limit is 1 complex object, you need to put both of them in one dto .

Comment: @sayahimad  have a sample? is it really work considering the list has more than 1 row? i tried to push or append the list in DTO_PartWO with so many ways but all not worked

Comment: thanks All for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way, but it is working fine, instead using serialize, serializeArray work good so I can add list parameter in form, so this is the code I use:

```
function SaveWorkOrder() 
{
    debugger;
    var dd = $('#tbParts').DataTable().rows().data().toArray();
    var vDataDet = new Array();

    // step 1 serialize array the form
    var data = $("#WorkOrderForm").serializeArray();

    //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
    $.each(dd, function (i, value) {
       debugger;

       data[data.length] = { name: "PartsList[" + i + "].Line", value: i };    
       data[data.length] = { name: "PartsList[" + i + "].PartCode", value: value[1] };  
       data[data.length] = { name: "PartsList[" + i + "].PartName", value: value[2] };  
       debugger;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Transactions/WorkOrder/SaveWorkOrder',
        data: data,
        success: function (mdl)
        {
           debugger;
        },
        error: function (mdl)
        {
           debugger;
        }
     })
}
```

This is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult SaveWorkOrder(DTO_WorkOrder objWork)
 {
    //something
 }
```

This is the models:

```
 public class DTO_WorkOrder
 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string WoNo { get; set; }
    public string ReqNo { get; set; }
    public string ReqSparepartDate { get; set; }
    public List<DTO_PartsWO> PartsList { get; set; }
 }

 public class DTO_PartsWO
 {
    public string WoNo { get; set; }
    public Int32 Line { get; set; }
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
 }
```

you can see  the result in picture[List in Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr6nK.png)  and [detail List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1HKb.png).